# Android - switch between button styles

Tags: android, android-styles

I am starting with Android development. I am trying to apply a different style on a button after a event occurred, programmatically.
I have two xml files with two styles. The first style is set to the button in the activity xml file. 
I found a piece of code that works perfectly! This:

```
 btnX1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_set1));
```

However, to use it, I have to switch my `android:minSdkVersion="16"` from `11`.

Is there a way to write this line of code compatible with `android:minSdkVersion=11` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setBackground` was introduced in [API level 16](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), while
`setBackgroundResource` in [API level 1.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Use the API level 1 function Ex:

```
btnX1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_btn_set1);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks to all three who have reply to my question. Your suggestion works well! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The whole Android project has extensive documentation, of every single object and XML option. 
Try to search Google for things like `Android Button` and it will take you to the specific developer.android.com page with all methods.

You can use one of these:

```
public void setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable background)

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 16.
use setBackground(Drawable) instead


public void setBackgroundResource (int resid)

Added in API level 1
Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.

Related XML Attributes
android:background
Parameters
resid   The identifier of the resource.
```

Its probably best to just use setBackgroundResource, no use in first making a Drawable from your Resource.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
btnX1 .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_btn_set1)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)